# CakePHP Multiple Named Parameters in Link

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I'm using a link to name a parameter that I need in a form on the next page.   Here is the link code:

```
    echo $this->Html->link('Email', array('controller' => 'emails', 'action' => 'add', 'contact_email' => $model), array('class' => 'button add'));
```

The purpose of this is to save an email to the database, and then send the email (both of which work).

I want to return to the page that they were on when they clicked the link, but don't know how to access that model and id after they've gone through two more page...

Here's add.ctp

```
<div class="universities form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Email');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php __('Add Email'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('subject');
        echo $this->Form->input('email_text');
        echo $this->Form->hidden('email', array('value' => $this->params['named']['contact_email']));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('user_from', array('value' => $this->Session->read('User.id')));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('created', array('value' => date("Y-m-d")));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('modified', array('value' => date("Y-m-d")));
                echo $this->Form->hidden('model', array('value' => $this->params['named']['model']));

    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
</div>
```

The real issue -- where to redirect?

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => $this->data['Email']['model'], 'action' => 'view', $this->data['model']['id']));
```

After implementing answer one, I get these errors on redirect (email saves and sends successfully though, so its just redirect issue).

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: Email::$enabled [CORE/cake/libs/controller/component.php, line 142]
Code | Context
            $component =& $this->_loaded[$name];

            if ($component->enabled === true && method_exists($component, 'beforeRedirect')) {
Component::beforeRedirect() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/component.php, line 142
Controller::redirect() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 678
EmailsController::add() - APP/controllers/emails_controller.php, line 54
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 83
Warning: mkdir() [http://php.net/function.mkdir]: Permission denied in /Users/jwg2s/Sites/fundvista/cake/libs/folder.php on line 498
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/jwg2s/Sites/fundvista/cake/libs/debugger.php:673) [CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 742]
Code | Context
header - [internal], line ??
Controller::header() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 742
Controller::redirect() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 721
EmailsController::add() - APP/controllers/emails_controller.php, line 54
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 83
Warning: mkdir() [http://php.net/function.mkdir]: Permission denied in /Users/jwg2s/Sites/fundvista/cake/libs/folder.php on line 498
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest, is to build a full return URI using:

```
$this->params['controller']
$this->params['action'];
$this->params['pass'];
```

So it would look something like this:

```
$returnUrl = $this->params['controller'] . '/' . $this->params['action'] . '/' . implode('/', $this->params['pass']);
// let's also replace the slashes with, say, underscores
$returnUrl = str_replace('/', '_', $returnUrl);

echo $this->Html->link('Email', array('controller' => 'emails', 'action' => 'add', 'contact_email' => $model, 'returnUrl' => $returnUrl), array('class' => 'button add'));
```

in add.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('returnUrl', array('value' => $this->params['named']['returnUrl']));
```

and in email's controller

```
$this->redirect('/' . str_replace('_', '/', $this->data['Email']['returnUrl']));
```

Comment: plus 1 because underscore rocks

Answer (score 0):

`$this->redirect($this->referer(array('action' => 'index')));`

where `index` is your default action if the referring link doesn't exist.

[read up here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/987/referer)

e.g your user is on `content/view/my-content`, he clicks `emails/add`, fills in his details, submits. the referring page is `content/view/my-content`, so he (should) be redirected back there.

Comment: The action they would be coming from would be view, so should I replace index with view?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to app_controller.php:

```
public function sendEmail($to,$from,$subject,$body,$headers=array(),$save_to_db=true)
    {
        if($save_to_db == true)
        {
            //do model crap here
            $this->Email->create();

            $data = array(
                'email' => $to,
                'subject' => $subject,
                'email_text' => $body,
                'user_from' => $from,
            // map fields here
            );
            if($this->Email->save($data) == false) 
            {
                $this->log("Email to '$to' from '$from' with subject '$subject' failed to save into the database!");
            }
        } // end save to db

        $email = new EmailComponent();
        //$email->startup($this);

        //reeset email component
        $email->reset();


        /* SMTP Options */
        $email->smtpOptions = array(
            'port'=>'25', 
            'timeout'=>'30',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username'=>'###########',
            'password'=>'###########',
        );

        /* Set delivery method */
        //$email->delivery = 'smtp';
        $email->from = $from;
        $email->to = $to;
        $email->subject = $subject;
        $email->replyTo = $from;
        $email->from = '############ <' . $subject . '>';
        $email->sendAs = 'html'; //Send as 'html', 'text' or 'both' (default is 'text')

        $success = $email->send($this->data['Email']['email_text']);
        if($success == false)
        {
            $this->log("Email to '$to' from '$from' with subject '$subject' failed to send!");
        }

        return true;
    } // end sendEmail
```

And then called the function after setting variables in my emails controller. (e.g. the $to, $from, $subject, $body, $headers)